# Python 3+ Is It Possible to Replace if in and elif in Using a Switcher

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement, switchers

I know how to use a dictionary as a switcher in Python. I'm not sure how to use one for my specific case. I think I will just need to use if, elif, and else but hopefully I am proved wrong by the community :)

I want to make a find/replace function for certain characters in strings. The string is at least one sentence but usually more and comprised of many words.

Basically what I am doing is the following:

```
if non-breaking hyphen in string:  # string is a sentence with many words
  replace non-breaking hyphen with dash

elif en dash in string:
  replace en dash with dash

elif em dash in string:
  replace em dash with dash

elif non-breaking space in string:
  replace non-breaking space with space
```

.... and so forth

The only thing I can think of is splitting the string apart into separate sub-strings and then looping through them then the dictionary switcher would work. But this would obviously add a lot of extra processing time and the purpose of using a dictionary switcher is to save time.

I could not find anything on this specific topic searching everywhere.

Is there a way to use a switcher in Python using if in and elif in?

Comment: Looks like a good fit for regular expressions to me.  One regex for each `if` clause, and you won't need any conditional logic.

Comment: @cxw If you need one regex per `if` clause, what's the point of using regex instead of string operations?

Comment: You want just `if` statements not `elif`.  If there's a `en dash` in `string`, that doesn't mean you want to ignore the `em dash` in string too, does it?  If each thing you want to replace is a single character, you should use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

Comment: But is it truly necessary to have `if`s here in the first place? Why not just perform the replacements without checking whether the character is present first? `if "." in s: s = s.replace(".", "-")` has the same behavior as `s = s.replace(".", "-")` by itself.

Comment: @Kevin  thanks, I will change that since what I'm doing is redundant. For the sake of this question lets assume I am not replacing text and doing some other operation based on if something is in a string, is it possible to create a dictionary switcher?

Comment: Why isn't anyone recommending str.translate?

Comment: @coldspeed: Patrick Haugh did.

Comment: Suggestion for the OP: Change all the `replace X with Y` things to `print(Y)` to make it more obvious that you're asking for a way to rewrite those `if...elif` statements in a more DRY fashion.

Comment: I think by giving string replacement as an example use of what you want to do you've led most of the answerers astray, since there are several string-replacement specific solutions to this problem. The more general problem is less amenable to a tidy and efficient solution (especially if you really do want `elif`s, which usually wouldn't make sense in the text replacement situations; you'd more often just want successive `if`s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) solution

```
replacements = {
    '\u2011': '-',  # non breaking hyphen
    '\u2013': '-',  # en dash
    '\u2014': '-',  # em dash
    '\u00A0': ' ',  # nbsp
}

trans = str.maketrans(replacements)
new_string = your_string.translate(trans)
```

Note that this only works if you want to replace single characters from the input.  `{'a': 'bb'}` is a valid `replacements`, but `{'bb': 'a'}` is not.

Comment: The issue I see here is that you will replace all at once, contrary to pseudo code implementation of OP

Comment: @BenjaminToueg I'm operating under the impression that this is what they actually wanted, even if it wasn't what they wrote.

Comment: @Patrick Haugh  sorry I wasn't as clear as you would have liked. It is difficult to explain in text. This is what I was after, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just to show that regex is a valid solution, and some timings:

```
replacements = {
    '\u2011': '-',
    '\u2013': '-',
    '\u2014': '-',
    '\u00A0': ' ', 
}

import re
s = "1‑‑‑‑2–––––––3————————"

re.sub(
    '|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in replacements),
    lambda x: replacements[x.group()], s
)
# Result
1----2-------3--------
```

***Timings*** (**`str.trans`** wins and is also cleaner)

```
s = "1‑‑‑‑2–––––––3————————"
s *= 10000

%timeit re.sub('|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in replacements), lambda x: replacements[x.group()], s)
90.7 ms ± 182 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [733]: %timeit s.translate(trans)
15.8 ms ± 59.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: The main advantage to this approach is that it works with multiple character substrings that you may want to replace. I'd suggest using `'|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in replacements)` to avoid any issues if there are regex-relevant characters to be replaced (and there's no need to call `keys()`). I'm not sure the `'({})'.format(...)` part is necessary, you can just use `x|y` from the `join` call as the pattern directly, as the replacement works with no capturing group at all.

Comment: Yea, was working on cleaning the regex up, thanks for the suggestions, I'll update

Answer (score 1):

Although Benjamin's answer might be right, it is case-specific, while your question has a rather general-purpose tone to it. There is a universal functional approach (I've added Python 3.5 type annotations to make this code self-explanatory):

```
from typing import TypeVar, Callable, Iterable

A = TypeVar('A')
B = TypeVar('B')
Predicate = Callable[[A], bool]
Action = Callable[[A], B]
Switch = Tuple[Predicate, Action]

def switch(switches: Iterable[Switch], default: B, x: A) -> B:
    return next(
        (act(x) for pred, act in switches if pred(x)), default
    )

switches = [
    (lambda x: '\u2011' in x, lambda x: x.replace('\u2011', '-')),
    (lambda x: '\u2013' in x, lambda x: x.replace('\u2013', '-'))
]
a = "I'm–a–string–with–en–dashes"

switch(switches, a, a) # if no switches are matched, return the input
```

This is quite superfluous in your case, because your example boils down to a regex operation. Take note, while `switches` can be any iterable, you might want to use something with predictable iteration order, i.e. any `Sequence` type (e.g. `list` or `tuple`), because the first action with a matched predicate will be used.

Comment: Good solution, but unreadable. It would help a lot if you added a usage example so people can figure out how to use it.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I've hesitated to add an example, because the solution is quite superfluous in the context of OP's example. Nevertheless, here you are.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty annoying to have to write a bunch of lambdas. It's probably more useful as recipe than a function. It'd look much cleaner with a loop with the lambdas inlined.

Comment: @Aran-Fey in general, the point of using a function is the ability to apply it partially to a list of switches (e.g. `replace_dashes = partial(switch, switches)` or even `partial(switch, switches, default)`, if the default is fixed, too) and reuse the switcher multiple times in various places/expressions allowing for expressive (in the functional programming sense) code.